# Firebase auth with PHP, am i using it right? is it secure?

Tags: security, javascript

So I have a form and in the form i ask the user to enter his phone number to be verified, and then his information will be inserted into DB with PHP queries.

I used this code:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "******",
    authDomain: "*****",
    databaseURL: "https://****",
    projectId: "*****",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "*****",
    appId: "1:****:*****"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // Create a Recaptcha verifier instance globally
  // Calls submitPhoneNumberAuth() when the captcha is verified
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
    "recaptcha-container",
    {
      size: "normal",
      callback: function(response) {
        submitPhoneNumberAuth();
      }
    }
  );

  // This function runs when the 'sign-in-button' is clicked
  // Takes the value from the 'phoneNumber' input and sends SMS to that phone number
  function submitPhoneNumberAuth() {
    var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
    var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
      .then(function(confirmationResult) {
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  // This function runs when the 'confirm-code' button is clicked
  // Takes the value from the 'code' input and submits the code to verify the phone number
  // Return a user object if the authentication was successful, and auth is complete
  function submitPhoneNumberAuthCode() {
    var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
    confirmationResult
      .confirm(code)
      .then(function(result) {
        var user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  //This function runs everytime the auth state changes. Use to verify if the user is logged in
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log("USER LOGGED IN");
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
      console.log("USER NOT LOGGED IN");
    }
  });
```

to verify the user's phone number. and in the form i used this :

```
 <div class="verifyCon">
                    <div class="SMSBox Padding2">
                        <div>
                            <span class="Text3"> phone number </span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input class="InptText" type="tel" id="phoneNumber" maxlength="10" minlength="10" name="uphone" required>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="SMSBut" onclick="submitPhoneNumberAuth()">
                                <h2 id="sign-in-button" class="Text2"> send </h2>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="SMSBox Padding2">
                        <div>
                            <span class="Text3"> code </span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input class="InptText" type="text" id="code" name="code" maxlength="6" minlength="6" required>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="SMSBut" onclick="submitPhoneNumberAuthCode()">
                                <h2 id="check-in-button" class="Text2"> check </h2>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My questions:

- Is it secure? can the user get configuration info from the file? if so how to secure it?
- Is there a way to make sure the user won't just submit the form without verifying the phone number?
- Do I need to add ReCaptcha in the form page, or the one with auth will be enough?
- I'm not good with JavaScript, so please any suggestions will be appreciated.